# What is average weight of Newzealand Albino rabbit?

Tags: rabbits

I have female newzealand albino rabbit of 1 year and she weighs 1.8 Kg is she underweight?

Her diet is Meadow Hay , Pellets and fresh veggie and grass.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a picture of her to the question? So that we might see how big she is.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand_rabbit Here they should have around 4.5 kg. Please add a photo, then it is clear to see, if your rabbit is just small, another breed or underweight.

Comment: Added image in question

Comment: For me it looks not underweight. It would be more easy to see, if it stands and one could see the shape of the belly. Sorry for not asking for the image more clearly with description.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing a rabbit savvy vet is the best way to know for sure if your rabbit is underweight. I have had pet rabbits in the past and have worked with a rabbit rescue group. Aside from seeing a vet the best way to tell if a rabbit is the correct weight is by looking at their shape. They should have a little distinguishable curve to their hips.

If they don't have this it could be a sign they are overweight. If the curve is really exaggerated and their hip and rib bones seem to be protruding out and feel jagged to the touch it could be a sign that they are under weight. [The House Rabbit](http://www.therabbithouse.com/diet/rabbit-weight.asp) has good images and descriptors to illustrate what under, over, and ideal weight rabbits look like.